# Can I assign custom name for path converters in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to assign custom name for `slug` path converter in `urlpatterns` of my 
Now it looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path(
        route="<slug:category>/",
        view=views.Category.as_view(),
        name="shop_category"
    ),
    ...
]
```

In this view I'm using `DetailListView`. The slug contains only ASCII characters, but anyway it doesn't let me in. After some manipulations with passed value, I return from `get` with `return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)` line.

Then it throws me an error:

> AttributeError: Generic detail view Category must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

But if I change in `category` name in `urlpatterns` to `slug`, error disappears.

---

Now, the question: can I assign custom name for path converters in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define custom name using [`slug_url_kwarg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_url_kwarg) attribute in your view class:

```
class Category(DetailView):
    slug_url_kwarg = "category"
```